# Does Team Foundation Server support "packaging" of work-items?

Tags: tfs, workitem

Consider this scenario:

- The project manager orders 10 bug fixes from the developer team.
- 10 work-items are added to `Team Foundation Server`.
- These work-items are then put in an order-form.

Would it be possible to automate the last step? Something like creating a bag of work-items that can then be pulled into a `Word` document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something [WordToTFS](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/11/15/publishing-requirements-from-word-to-tfs-via-wordtotfs.aspx) would help you with.

It's not yet fully automated, but you can import a specific list of work items and merge them into a document.

Comment: I believe this will suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on upcoming ALM Rangers Word4TFS plugin: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/tags/tfswp/

Comment: Interesting. Bookmarked :) But it doesn't solve my problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Commercial offering: [TeamSpec](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/features/microsoft-word-integration.aspx)

Might be worth downloading the trial version and seeing if it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect MS Word and TFS using following tool:

http://www.smartoffice4tfs.com/pages/smart-word-features

Answer (score 0):

The TFS client includes plugins that can open work items in Excel - you can embed the Excel table in a Word document.  In that way you could pull a known work-item-query's results into a Word document.

(Not sure if this is really a programming question, though...)